# Ng2-map/Ng2-ui - Angular2 difference in plotting geo codes

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here I have plotted a circle with

`center="59.82352331557955,-43.59219821635634" & radius ="567.6796059859073"`

I am giving two links , one is plotted using ngui-map and second one is the the marker point set as the same circles center in google map.

Link1: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rLhq9cjl5Pu927lkkDTj?p=preview)

Link2: [Google map](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/59%C2%B049'24.7%22N+43%C2%B035'31.9%22W/@59.9212595,-43.7853755,9.75z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d59.8235233!4d-43.5921982)

There is a huge difference between them. Can anyone help? Is this my mistake or bug in the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK(I have been using `ng2-ui/map` for some while), the `marker`'s `position` accept **array** which contains `lat, lng`, and `circle`'s `center` accept `object` which contains properties of `lat/lng`, `ng2-ui/map` will call `geocode` to search for result if they are binded with `string`(your current plunker).

refer [code](https://github.com/ng2-ui/map/blob/master/src/directives/circle.ts), and fixed **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yCa61dao9004Le9bhIDb?p=preview)**.